# mysql performance <, > for varchar vs integer

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to save unknown datatypes to a field. I therefore have to use varchar instead of integer (because the data could also be a string)

```
id, filter1, filter2
1, male, 24
2, female, 53
```

In this case filter1 is gender and filter2 is age. Is there a big performance impact if I query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE filter2 > 30
```

compared to using integer?

Comment: The opening sentence of your question indicates that you did not put enough thought into your application.

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors which could be specific to you. The best thing to do is to simply test it yourself. It is not difficult at all. I tested it on a table of 9 million rows, MyISAM, on an indexed column, and I found that varchar seemed somewhat slower, but there wasn't much in it.

Comment: @DanBracuk Unfortunately it is a legacy system that I have to redesign. That's why I posted this question. I am currently reviewing the DB design

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
where filter > 30
```

Then MySQL will do what you want -- but you might get strange results.  If you had a column with the value `'44x'`, then it would also be chosen by the filter.  Why?  Because MySQL will convert `filter` to a string.  In addition, the type conversion generally precludes the use of an index.

If you use strings:

```
where filter > '30'
```

Then you don't have the string conversion problem, but you will get all the strings that start with letters.

In other words, don't mix types like this.  Values should be stored in their native types.  You should revisit your data model -- you probably want a column called `age` somewhere (or better yet, date-of-birth).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know beforehand what the filters are. Customers can define them themselves. So I do not know if it is going to be a string or number. The only restriction that I currently impose is that there is a maximum of 5 filters (i.e. 5 columns in my table: filter1 ... filter5)